# Batch-file, running application in order vs. all at once

Tags: windows, batch, command-line

If I create a batch file (batch.bat) and typed this in:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"
"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
```

The applications in question would run in order, first WinRAR would load and once closed, Notepad would load next in order.

**Q:** How do I syntax the batch file to run all application at the same time, I want both WinRAR and Notepad to open at the same time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `start` instead:

```
start "" "command here"
```

**Edit:** Do not miss the first pair of empty quotes, this is the title of the process/window.

```
start <title> <command> <parameters>
```

See `start /?` for further details.

Comment: To be a pedantic snerk, I have to point out that this *wont* work in DOS :-) It will work in cmd.exe, though.

Comment: Of course. DOS doesn't even have multitasking.

Answer (score 1):

create shortcuts to the exectutables and copy them into a folder (i chose Z:\Temp), then use this:

```
"z:\temp\NOTEPAD.EXE.lnk"
"z:\temp\WinRAR.exe.lnk"
```

Or use [Batch Runner](http://corz.org/windows/software/batch-runner/), a simple program that enables you to run lots of other programs, in one big batch.